# issue with with(nolock) in sql server

Tags: sql-server

I am not use with(nolock) in my store procedure but my transaction is not suspended

```
ALTER PROC [dbo].[TY]
@id int
AS
BEGIN
SELECT *
FROM students
where id = @id
END
```

I am update the data and execute the store procedure but my transaction is not suspended

```
begin tran
update students set studName='s' where id=1

EXEC TY 2

exec TY 3

select *
from students
```

see result:

[image]

- now I am use with(nolock) in my store procedure

```
ALTER PROC [dbo].[TY]
@id int
AS
BEGIN
SELECT *
FROM students with(nolock)
where id = @id
END
```

--I am update the data and execute the store procedure

```
begin tran
update students set studName='j' where id=1

EXEC TY 2

exec TY 3

select *
from students
```

[image]

if I not use with(nolock) then same output and if I am use with(nolock) then same output

not able to find why when I not use with(nolock) then why my transaction is not suspended?

please help

Comment: Try from a different connection

Comment: What do you mean by the transaction isn't suspended? All the those statements are in the same transaction so would have access to any tables locked by that transaction.

Comment: You can uncommitted changes made on the same connection because they share the same transaction. Queries on other connections will block if they attempt to read uncommitted data unless you specify 1) NOLOCK, 2) READ UNCOMMITTED, or 3) use SNAPSHOT isolation level (or have the READ_COMMITTED_SPAPSHOT database option on).

Comment: Use a second query window (which will use another connection). Note that `NOLOCK` is generally a bad idea